# LDAP authentication without managerDN and manager password

Tags: spring-security, ldap, basic-authentication, spring-ldap

I am writing an application in Java Spring framework to perform Active Directory LDAP authentication.
I am succeeding in connecting to my organization LDAP.

Here is the configuration settings:Spring-security.xml

```
<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
    access-denied-page="/oops">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/*"
        access="isAuthenticated()" />


    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/logout" />

</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider
        user-search-filter="(&amp;(sAMAccountname={0})(objectCategory=user))"
        user-search-base="DC=am, DC=example, DC=com" group-search-filter="(&amp;(sAMAccountname={0})(objectCategory=group))"
        group-search-base="DC=am, DC=example, DC=com">
    </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>




<security:ldap-server url="ldaps://myserver.am.example.com:4567"
manager-dn="CN=Johnson \, Mitchell, OU=San Francisco,DC=am,DC=example,DC=com"
manager-password="sdvsdvsvs" />
```

My question here is that,is there any way to authenticate LDAP without supplying manager-dn and manager-password in security:ldap-server tag.
Please provide a solution to this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible: you can let the user who is actualy logging in connecting to the LDAP himself to test his credential and fetch its userdata.

AuthenticationManager configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(domain, url, rootDn);
    activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setSearchFilter(searchFilter);
    auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider);
}
```

Spring security does two things:

- Let the user log in with his username and password
- Find the user to fetch user info, groups, etc. For this step, you must specify a searchFilter that can find a user based on it's username, like "userPrincipalName={0}" where {0} is the provided username.

Answer (score -2):

Define an administrative user who has the necessary permissions, and use that. You certainly shouldn't use the managerDN for anything in your application.

Comment: Thanks. How to give the above mentioned settings,i mean defining an admin user?